# unable to set http_referer

Tags: php, http-referer

How can I set my `http_referer` location in my `logout.php` page after signin(using signin.php) which checks & successfully login redirects to joomla.php where i gave logout link(using a href) now i want to click on logout & go to `signin. php & i got http_referer is joomla.php so hw can i set logout.php

1. **Code: Signin.php**

   ```
   $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   echo $referer;
   if ($referer == 'http://localhost/MinProject/reg.php')
   {
       echo "Registration SuccessFully";
   }

   else if($referer=='http://localhost/MinProject/changepassword.php')
   {
       echo"Change Password SuccessFully";
   }
   ```
2. **joomla.php**

   ```
   <html>
       <body>
           <table width="100%">
               <tr>
                   <td width="20%" height="32" align="right" class="unm">
                       <?php
                       session_start();
                       if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
                       {
                           $name =$_SESSION['username'];
                           echo "Welcome ".$name;
                        }
                       ?>
                   </td>
                   <td width="64%" height="32" align="right">
                       <a href="changepassword.php">ChangePassword</a>
                   </td>
                   <td width="10%" align="right">
                       <a href="logout.php">logout</style></a>
                   </td>
                   <td width="11%"></td>
                   <td width="5%"></td>
                   <td width="5%"></td>
                   <td width="5%"></td>
               </tr>
           </table> 
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. **logout.php**

   ```
   session_start();
   unset($_SESSION['username']);
   session_destroy();
   response.setHeader("Location: http://localhost/MinProject/logout.php");
   header("Location: Signin.php");
   exit();
   ```

Comment: never use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for something like this

Comment: You can't "set http_referer", it is part of the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed so you should not use that.

Looking at your code i think you are trying to achieve.

```
$Message  = $_SESSION['MESSAGE'];//set the message Registration SuccessFully if registration else set it as Change Password SuccessFully or accordingly
if (isset($Message) and userhasidentity)
{
    echo $Message;
}else
{
   header('location:logout.php');
}
```